# Is this boolean conversion correct?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I have a boolean expression that looks like this

```
(!B and !C) or (B and !D) or (A and !C)
```

And I need to convert it so that it only has and operations. So I came up with this result

```
(B and C) and (!B and D) and (!A and C)
```

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong? I just want to make it sure.

I also know that

```
A or B
```

Is equilevant to

```
!(!A and !B)
```

Comment: B&~B is constant 0. Thus, your second formula is always false, whereas the first one is not always false.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply your last expression to replace `OR` by `AND`, you can rewrite your Boolean expression to

```
!(!(!B and !C) and !(B and !D) and !(A and !C))
```

But the Boolean expression can be simplified to

```
!C or (B and !D)
```

Karnaugh map:

```
         cd
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
ab    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

This can be expressed as

```
!(C and !(B and !D))
```

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions are not equivalent. The second one is the dual of the first one. The expression is already in the minimal Sum-of-Product form.